# I would like to overwrite two columns of my table from another table (pandas, jupyter notebook, python)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook, overwrite

I have a main table ex:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N56h0.png)

John has 4 apple shares, Katie has 10 Tesla shares and Emma has 50 Samsung shares.
But everyday, the stock share prices change and I want to update it once a day.

and the format is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etCyF.png)

I'd like to overwrite this specific two rows into the main table to be looked like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSfGE.png)

I tried to use 'merge' function / 'concat' function but there are always duplicates. Anyone knows a better way? Thank you :)

Comment: Please include your actual code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can work for your question,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'name': ['John','Katie','Emma'],
    'Stock name': ['Apple', 'Tesla','Samsung'], 
   'Price': [160,800,70],
  'country': ['US','US','KOR'],
  'No. Stock': ['4','10','50'],}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)



 data_2 = { 'Stock name': ['Apple', 'Tesla','Samsung'], 
   'Price': [150,900,110]
                }

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

 df1['Price'] = df2['Price'].values
```

So final data should look like this,

```
name    Stock name  Price   country  No. Stock
John    Apple        150    US           4
Katie   Tesla        900    US          10
Emma    Samsung      110    KOR         50
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This is what I wanted!

Just curious, if data_2 was 
 data_2 = { 'Stock name': [''Tesla, 'Apple','Samsung'], 
   'Price': [900,150,110]
which means Tesla and Apple is in different order, does this still work? Or it's only considered as [150,900,100]? Thank you!!!

Comment: If I want to connect apple 150 / tesla 900 / samsung 110, then better to use dictionary? Because in my knowledge, merge or concat is not working. Thank you

Comment: the same method  wont work for dictionary because order change. As you say If you want to connect them, should use dictionary. good luck with your code